# Grouping the same numbers from a long list of numbers in an array in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, data-structures, grouping

What is an efficient way of grouping a long list of numbers array in to smaller arrays of the same number  in objective-C?
or if there is a standard library for this.

Comment: Could you show an example? What are you trying to achieve? There are multiple very efficient structures in existence that could help, but it's hard to understand what you need without additional information.

Comment: [1,3,4,6,8,9,5,43,3,44,23,4,4,9,5,3,1,9]  to  [1,1][3,3,3][4,4,4][6][8][9,9,9][5,5][43][44][23]. my actual list is not just a number, each number represent another list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoa has a very nice data structure called [`NSCountedSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) created specifically for dealing with sets of objects that may repeat. When you add a sequence of objects (say, numbers) to it, the structure remembers the number of times each object was added.

For example, if you start with a sequence that looks like this

```
1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 2, 5, 6, 2, 4, 3
```

and add these numbers to a counted set, the structure would be as follows:

```
N - Count
- - -----
1 - 1
2 - 3
3 - 2
4 - 2
5 - 2
6 - 1
```

With this set in hand you can construct your array of arrays, or simply keep the coutnted set as a more efficient representation.

Here is an example:

```
NSArray *data = @[@1, @3, @5, @2, @4, @2, @5, @6, @2, @4, @3];
NSCountedSet *cs = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:data];
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [cs objectEnumerator];
NSNumber *value;
while ((value = [enumerator nextObject])) {
    NSLog(@"%@ - %d", value, [cs countForObject:value]);
}
```